# hdiutil convert "Resource temporarily unavailable"

Tags: macos, installation, disk, iso

```
hdiutil detach disk9s2                                                                                       
"disk9" ejected.

hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o disk9s2/snolepinst.img /Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso
hdiutil: convert failed - Resource temporarily unavailable
```

I am not trained at this, but follow directions well.

I'm trying to make an install USB thumb drive for High Sierra. I have the .iso file and have tried many variations of the hdiutil convert with no success, getting No such directory until the last iteration, when I obtained "Resource temporarily unavailable." I am using a 2020 Intel Mac with Monterey 12.6.2 to do it. The usb is HFS+, the current Mac is APFS.

Here is debug:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o disk9s2/snolepinst.img /Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso -debug         ─╯
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIIsInitialized: returning YES
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: entry with
file:///Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso
writeable: false
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: entry
file:///Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso
writeable: false
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 0 CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::newProbe score 100 for file:///Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 1 CBundleBackingStore
CBundleBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 2 CRAMBackingStore
CRAMBackingStore::probe: scheme "file": not ram: or ramdisk: scheme.
CRAMBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 3 CDevBackingStore
CDevBackingStore::newProbe: not /dev/disk or /dev/rdisk (/Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso).
CDevBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CDevBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 4 CCURLBackingStore
CCURLBackingStore::probe: scheme is: file
CCURLBackingStore::probe: not recognized URL scheme.
CCURLBackingStore::probe: score -1000 for file:///Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  4, score    -1000, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: probing interface 5 CVectoredBackingStore
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe not "vectored" scheme.
CVectoredBackingStore::newProbe score -1000 for file:///Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: interface  5, score    -1000, CVectoredBackingStore
DIBackingStoreInstantiatorProbe: selecting CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: CBSDBackingStore
CBSDBackingStore::setPermission: opening /Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso
CBSDBackingStore::OpenLockFriendly: mapping flags 0x00000000 -> 0x00000014 (locks are MANDATORY)
CBSDBackingStore:OpenLockFriendly: could not open with lock 35
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: instantiator returned 35
DIBackingStoreNewWithCFURL: returning 35
DIResolveURLToBackingStore: unable to resolve to any backing store class. 35. 
DIResolveURLToDiskImage: resolving backing store/file encoding failed. 35. 
convert: unable to recognize "/Users/jaygamel/Desktop/snolepinst.iso":
Resource temporarily unavailable.hdiutil: convert failed - Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: Your first two lines appear to eject a disk then write on the disk you just ejected - seems odd!

Comment: disk9s2 used to be a partition on a mounted disk image, but when you detached it that virtual device was removed (note: the image will not have been removed, just the virtual devices it was attached as). When you use `disk9s2/snolepinst.img`, that does something completely unrelated to devices; it tries to use "disk9s2" as the name of a subdirectory (under your current working directory), which doesn't make any sense. This may not be the only problem, but try using just `-o snolepinst.img`.